# Cannot detect Browser when using Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, internet-explorer, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to prevent users from using my website in Internet Explorer.

What I want to do is to detect their browser on the server side, and if it is Internet Explorer, I would redirect them to a page, saying "IE is not supported"

I have tried detecting browser using both `Browser` and `UserAgent`, in the development environment, I get the following values:

```
var browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;     // <-- InternetExplorer
var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent; // <-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

But when I run the same code in my test environment (test server is behind Application Load Balancer) I get the following values:

```
var browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;     // <-- Unknown
var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent; // <-- ELB-HealthChecker/2.0
```

Is there any way that I could detect the browser behind ELB?

Comment: The problem was that CloudFront was not forwarding `User-Agent` header... After whitelisting `User-Agent` header in CloudFront, the values are coming through

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.